# Why is `contenteditable` regex not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Im trying to validate this `content editable` value but it doesnt work if you apply more than one blank space. Whats wrong with this `regex`?

```js
var regex = /^([A-zñÑáéíóú&;0-9 ]{0,100})$/;

$("button").on("click", function() {
    if (regex.test($("#editable").text()) ) {
      console.log("valid");
    }
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="editable" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="plaintext-only" max="100" class="font-italic">Editable</span>

<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: FYI: `A-z` matches more than just letters. Have a look at an ASCII table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not in the regex: https://regex101.com/r/QP49FU/1

Everything *seems* to work if you remove the extra `contenteditable="true"` from your `<span>` tag:

```js
var regex = /^([A-zñÑáéíóú&;0-9 ]{0,100})$/;

$("button").on("click", function() {
    if (regex.test($("#editable").text()) ) {
      console.log("valid");
    }
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="editable" contenteditable="plaintext-only" max="100" class="font-italic">Editable</span>

<button>Check</button>
```

**But since** `contenteditable="plaintext-only"` **is not standardized, you should just remove that and edit the regex to accept the ['NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)**, because your original code will convert multiple spaces to those. So just add that to your character pattern:

```js
var regex = /^([A-zñÑáéíóú&;0-9\u00a0 ]{0,100})$/;

$("button").on("click", function() {
    if (regex.test($("#editable").text()) ) {
      console.log("valid");
    }
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="editable" contenteditable="true" max="100" class="font-italic">Editable</span>

<button>Check</button>
```

Using `\s` in the pattern is subjectively bad, because then the pattern accepts all kinds of whitespace characters, including ['FORM FEED (FF)' (U+000C)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm) and ['LINE TABULATION' (U+000B)'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm), which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

If you get code point for each character in the text using

```
Array.from(text).map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
```

For the space character, you get 160 or `A0`. This is [No-Break Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/). But the [Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/0020/) character's code point is 32.

```js
console.log(" ".codePointAt(0))
```

So, it is unable to match. If you replace the space with `\s`, it will match all whitespace characters

```js
var regex = /^([A-zñÑáéíóú&;0-9\s]{0,100})$/;

$("button").on("click", function() {
    const text = $("#editable").text();
    
    console.log(Array.from(text).map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)));
    
    if (regex.test(text) ) {
      console.log("valid");
    }
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="editable" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="plaintext-only" max="100" class="font-italic">Editable</span>

<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: This will give the output `valid`, when to user enters for example ['FORM FEED (FF)' (U+000C)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm) or ['LINE TABULATION' (U+000B)'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm), this might not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the content editable adds a non-breakable space, instead of a normal space when adding multiple spaces. This is because multiple space characters in HTML will be folded into one when displaying, and that's not what you want in this case.

Replace  with `\s` in the regex to also test for this:

```
var regex = /^([A-zñÑáéíóú&;0-9\s]{0,100})$/
```

Comment: This will match any whitespace characters, including ['FORM FEED (FF)' (U+000C)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm) and ['LINE TABULATION' (U+000B)'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm), this might not be desirable.